# Can HttpClientCodec/HttpServerCodec and HttpObjectAggregator be removed after websocket handshake completes?

Tags: binary, websocket, netty

I'm in the process of load testing a high performance websocket gateway application which supports 100K+ client websockets.  The requests are ALL Binary websocket messages and use our own Codec go to/from byte[] and our POJO.

The application is using Netty 4.0.12 on JDK 1.7.0_45.

I would like to make the websocket channel pipeline as efficient as possible to provide the maximum throughput with the least CPU utilization.  The first thought is to remove any unnecessary handlers.  The second will be to make sure our custom codec is working with the byte[]/ByteBuf properly, but that will be another post.

As a result, I wanted to see if the HTTP-related pipeline handlers can be removed from a newly created client/server channel once the websocket handshake is complete.  I'm assuming the websocket netty plumbing doesn't need any HTTP stuff, so please let me know if that's a wrong assumption.

If I can remove these programmatically, would you please let me know where in the pipeline that is typically done.

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is automatically removed for you after the handshake was completed. So no need for you to do it.